# Updating Location From multiple activities

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in android and I have an application in which a user creates an account.
Once the account is created, the user has access to plenty of activities.
I need to test the location of the user and update it no matter in which activity he's in.
How can I do that? Do I need to use a broadcast receiver or anything similar?

Answer (score 1):

For example, if you use a textview to show the location, all textviews in different activities could have the same name, using findviewbyid() to get the textview and update it in different activity.

Comment: Yeah but this will only work if I implemented a location listener in the same activity as the original textview right?
I don't want to make multiple location listeners in multiple activities. I would like to do it once and have it work no matter in which activity I am. Is that possible? If I'm mistaken, please do correct me. Thanks upfront buddy.

Comment: just make a static functions in a class (which will return lat and long) and always call that functions to get the location of the user , and in what ever activity you want to display, just call that static function and display as you want.

Comment: @user731077 I thought about that, but again what if I'm not the activity in which the listener is implemented? Wouldn't that make the listener stop working? I would like to keep the listener working no matter in what activity I am.

Comment: @ANON_BNR Which location technology do you use? Location code could be written in an another class and update a static location variable, you could get the static variable in the activity calss.

Comment: @user731077 Mate. I got the point of the static issue thingy. But the main problem is again, even if I created a class for the location method, I would have to create an instance in each activity which is a waste. Isn't there another method to make a Location grabbing method for the entire application once for all? Without the need to create a class from which a new instance is created in all of the activities?

Comment: as i understand your problem yet, for static method calling, you wont need making a new instance . just call MYClass.MYMethod(); and it will work. you can implement singleton pattern on your variables in class/method to avoid their new instances again and again.